# Divs on top of each other, bottom div edge showing.

Tags: html, css

I made this [sorta simple circular loader-thingy](http://jsfiddle.net/kylmark/rhxe8h3o/), whith two half circles covered with another two half circles that are positioned right on top of them. The covers rotate and reveal the bottom circles to make it look like a circular loading bar.

The problem is that the edge of the bottom circles are visible in some browsers, and there are some mobile browser issues with that as well. Is there a solution for this?

CSS

```
.wrap{
    position:relative;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    overflow:hidden;
    border-radius:50px;
}
.circle{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    width:50px;
    height:100px;
    background:black;
}
.cover{
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    width:50px;
    height:100px;
    background:white;
}
.halfcircleleft{
    width:50px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
.halfcircleleft .circle{
    z-index:3;
    border-radius:50px 0 0 50px;
}
.halfcircleleft .cover{
    z-index:4;
    border-radius:50px 0 0 50px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="halfcircleleft">
        <div class="circle"></div>
        <div class="cover"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="halfcircleright">
        <div class="circle"></div>
        <div class="cover"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: a) That's cool. b) I don't think you can get around this. It's almost impossible to have all browsers reflect the same pixel perfect version of html, especially when dealing with curves.

Comment: I was afraid of that. I was hoping there would be some trick to make it look the same, by using borders or something. Or that I had missed to use vendor prefixes on something..

Comment: Are you using a solid CSS reset block? Do you have any specific browsers that can be tested in or screenshots of it breaking?

Comment: You can use ready made jQuery plugin for this and that's works fine on almost all browsers. [timecircles](https://plugins.jquery.com/timecircles/).

Comment: no css reset used. right now the edge is showing in all browsers. I was working with a different version of it in safari yesterday and it was looking good then. I was using background color instead of a border then but that also made a visible edge in other browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about using a circle with transparent background and white border bigger than `hole`to put it over the border you want to remove?like:

```
.hole, .hole2{
    z-index:99;
    position:absolute;
    width:86px;
    height:86px;
    top:7px;
    left:7px;
    background:lightgrey;
    border-radius:50%;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:86px;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:38px;
    padding-right:2px;
}
.hole2 {
    background:transparent;
    border:4px solid white;
    width:106px;
    height:106px;
    top:-3px;
    left:-3px;
}
```

then just remove the `overflow:hidden`of `wrap`which it's not doing anything (at least in your example)

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rhxe8h3o/13/)**

Comment: I think I tried something similar before, and something was off on mobile. But this is slightly different and might actually work! I'll do some testing. Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help. gl with your project.